# How to query by term ID within a Timber Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, timber

I want to fetch a category from the posts terms based on an ID I have fetched.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
{{ dump(post.terms( {query:{taxonomy:'category',  ID: 64}})) }}
```

The taxonomy query limits the returned terms to just categories but the ID is ignored, returning both selected categories instead of just category 64.  I've also tried `p:`  and `id:`

Comment: Does it work if you use `object_ids` instead of `ID`?

Comment: no, I tried that with 64, [64] and ['64']

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing the point but if you know the ID of the category why don't you pick the category directly?

Comment: because i'm in a loop, in twig.  so can't do for eg. Timber\Term(6).
also, for some of the places I want to use this, I know the id, and want to know if it is in the post's terms

Comment: In that case you should use`has_term` to determine if term belongs to post, see https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#has_term you should be able to make `post.has_term(64, 'category')`

Comment: good one.  and combine with get_term(64, 'category') or similar to then return the object